# Change CSS based on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm wondering how would I change a CSS element in javascript..e.g if a user clicks a button it changed the background from white to black

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every DOM element has a `style` property that allows manipulation of CSS properties on that object as if you were mucking with it's `style` attribute.

The below will toggle the color of the document body but is equally applicable to other HTML elements.

```
<button onclick="document.body.style.background = (toggle = !toggle) ? 'black' : 'white'">Toggle Background</button>
```

As TheBuzzSaw points out, you need to camel case them.
So the JS property is `backgroundColor` instead of `background-color`.
The rule is basically

```
var javascriptProperty = cssStyleProperty.replace(
    /-([a-z])/g,
    function (_, followingLetter) { return followingLetter.toUpperCase(); });
```

but there are a few exceptions : since `float` is a keyword in many languages, the CSS style property is `cssFloat`.  The exceptions are explained under JavaScript syntax in the w3schools pages : http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp

> **JavaScript syntax:**    *object*`.style.cssFloat="left"`

Answer (score 0):

There are many properties/attributes that can be manipulated directly from JavaScript. You just need to know their names. They are usually strange camel case equivalents of the CSS property names. A quick Google search reveals lots of places to learn about this.

http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javastyle.html

Answer (score 0):

load new image with black color on click event of the button

Comment: This is a simple way...but go for attributes for programing perspective :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a framework, have a look at jQuery, especially this:
http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Framework agnostic script:

http://jsfiddle.net/chprpipr/kWRRN/1/